# Discord.js how to ignore a specific text and send the rest

Tags: discord.js, prefix

I'm trying to make an emoji library bot, which is private. The issue I'm facing is here:

```
  case 'madiamond' :
  case 'mashiningdiamond' :
    message.channel.send(`**${message.author.tag}** : <a:shiningdiamond:725331059369181284> ${message.content}`)
    message.delete({timeout: 1000});
  break;
```

I want to make it so it ignores the prefix and command, which is `e!madiamond`. The issue I'm facing is that when I use this command in Discord, it shows the message like this:

What I get:

> **Username#0000 : (the emoji) e!madiamond user message**

What I want:

> **Username#0000 : (the emoji) user message**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to dynamically remove the command portion of `message.content`. Then use [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the array back into a string.

```
case 'madiamond' :
case 'mashiningdiamond' :
   const filteredContent = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
   message.channel.send(`**${message.author.tag}** : <a:shiningdiamond:725331059369181284> ${filteredContent}`);
   message.delete({timeout: 10});
break;
```